# GaloisFS theory not field theory

Tags: logic, galois-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

Are there GaloisFS theories, more than field theory?

In the paper “Weak forms of elimination of imaginaries” by Enrique Casanovas and Rafel Farre ́ it is introduced the definition of GaloisFS theory as follow

> T codes Galois finite sets (T has GaloisFS), if for every set of real elements A and for every finite set C ⊆ acl(A) of tuples (of the same length) there exists a real tuple a such that Aut(M/Aa) = Aut(M /A{C}), i. e., for every automorphism f ∈ Aut(M /A), f(a) = a if and only if f(C) = C. Of course, it is enough to check the defining condition for finite sets A.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @amWhy Have some example of theory that codes Galois finite sets (GaloisFS)

Comment: Please ask a proper question.  "What are some examples ... ??

Answer (score 4):

In the paper you cite, immediately after the definition, the authors observe and prove:

1. EI implies GaloisEI (Fact 3.7(1)), and GaloisEI implies GaloisFS  (Proposition 3.9).
2. FS implies GaloisFS (Fact 3.7(1)).
3. acl = dcl implies GaloisFS (Fact 3.7(2)).

Together, these facts give an enormous number of examples of theories with GaloisFS.

Do you know any examples of theories with elimination of imaginaries, other than the theory of algebraically closed fields? What about examples of theories in which acl and dcl coincide? What about examples of theories without EI, but which code finite sets?

If you don't know any such examples, this paper is probably not the right thing for you to be reading right now. Start by working through a textbook in model theory with lots of examples, like Marker or Hodges.

On the other hand, if you do know such examples, and you're really looking for more exotic examples, e.g. theories with GaloisFS but not GaloisEI, then you need to ask a more precise question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The Tent-Ziegler doesn’t have examples about it. I have searched on Marker but it doesn’t seem have elimination of quantifiers, or he can use a different name. Can you say me witch chapter of the marker is about this argument?

Comment: @Focaccia You wrote "elimination of quantifiers", but I assume you meant "elimination of imaginaries". Marker doesn't treat elimination of imaginaries in general, instead he briefly introduces the $M^{\mathrm{eq}}$ construction at the end of Section 1.3 and uses it a lot in Chapters 6-8. The $M^{\mathrm{eq}}$ construction shows that *any* theory $T$ has a canonical expansion $T^{\mathrm{eq}}$ which eliminates imaginaries, and hence has GaloisFS. Hodges does treat elimination of imaginaries in more detail, especially in the big *Model Theory* book.

Comment: What I really meant, though, is that before jumping into technical research papers, it's a good idea to have a library of examples of first-order theories that you understand thoroughly. For example, I would expect a graduate student working with me to be able to come up with several examples of theories in which $\mathrm{acl} = \mathrm{dcl}$, off the top of their head, before we start reading research papers.